# Matlab equivalent for cv2.warpPerspective?

Tags: python, image, matlab

Is there a Matlab image function which does something similar as cv2.warpPerspective?
I would like to implement the following python line into Matlab:

```
image_OUT=cv2.warpPerspective(image_IN, matrix, (row, col), cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

My matrix is 3x3.

I tried with imwarp but get the following error(in Matlab):

```
Error using imwarp>parseInputsDisplacementFieldSyntax (line 303)
The value of 'DisplacementField' is invalid. Displacement field D must be of size MxNx2 or MxNxPx3.

Error in imwarp (line 172)
    [parsedInputs,catConverter,isInputCategorical] = parseInputsDisplacementFieldSyntax(varargin{:});
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html) clearly states that `imwarp` takes either a [tform object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html#btqog63-1-tform) or a displacement field. [Here's](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/2-d-and-3-d-geometric-transformation-process-overview.html) an overview of 2d transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out = imwarp(image_IN,projective2d(matrix'),'nearest');
```

Note that the transform convention in MATLAB is transposed from that of OpenCV.